# How to display data from two model in one view the given way in cakephp 1.3?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I'd like to display the data from the array in the order as shown in the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use nested foreach.

```
foreach($yourvariable as $data){
  echo $data['Category']['title'];
  foreach ($data['Product'] as $myproduct){
    echo $product['whateverfield1'];
    echo $product['whateverfield2'];
  }
}
```

Comment: _ thank you :) I think there should be $product instead of $myproduct ?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a [CakePHP Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1097/Creating-Helpers).  Then you can make a method inside that Helper that will generate the list markup you need.  Here's a quick-n-dirty...

```
class YourHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function your_method(array $modelData) {

        foreach ($modelData as $info) {

            $markup = '<div>'; 
            $markup .= '<h3>' . $info['Category']['title'] . '</h3>';
            $markup .= '<ul>';                

            $allProducts = $info['Product'];

            if (!empty($allProducts) {

                foreach ($allProducts as $productInfo) {

                     $markup .= '<li>' . $productInfo['desc'] . '</li>';

                 }

             } else {

                 $markup .= '<li>No products in this category!</li>';

             }

             $markup .= '</ul></div>';

         }

     return $markup;

 }
```

Ensure to include the helper in your controllers or `AppController` then you can use it in your views just like any other helper.

Obviously I haven't tested this out but with this method you should be able to have an arbitrary number of `children` and then an arbitrary number of `Products` within each of those.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That's a solid solution but isn't it a little unnecessary to load yet another class for something as simple as a nested foreach? I would probably just write this code in the view. Your way seems very cakey, though, I'll give you that

Comment: @Rob I'll admit that this does seem a little 'over-the-top'.  As I've used Cake more and more though I've found that I hate seeing that kind of code in the view.  It just makes it look cluttered to me.  Also I like that as the business model changes I can change the code in one helper...and not have to hunt through N views looking for all the nested loops.